EPS units in Gaussian
I computed some EPS on with Gaussian and I am visualizing them with GaussView. After defining the isovalue, I can still twist these two values:

that appear on the top of the Surface interface.
I couldn't find more about them in the manual, neither of Gaussian nor of Gaussview. Do you know what they represent and in what units? Thanks!
